# How to scrape multiple tables form HTML file in python?

Tags: python, html, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

OBJECTIVE:
Trying to scrape the contents of multiples HTML files and put into a csv file.

Looking for the unbolded items to be column headers and for the bolded information to fit into a row inside a csv file.

So far, I've been able to effectively get tables 1 and 2 (there are 5 total).

Believe I'm having difficulty scraping the data once there is more than one field on a single "row" (see table 3 as an example below and how it varies relative to table 1 & 2).

The first line of html for table 3 looks like this:

[image]

Notice multiple td's and th's in the tr.

**Example HTML:**
[image]

[image]

**CSV Formatting:**
[image]

**Page HTML:**

```
<div class="table-responsive" id="section-1">
    <h2>1.&nbsp;Identification de l'unité d'évaluation</h2>
    <table class="table table-borderless table-condensed">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td width="50%">Adresse&nbsp;:</td>
            <th width="50%">325 Chemin de la Pointe-Sud</th>
        </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Arrondissement&nbsp;:</td>
         <th>Arrondissement de Verdun</th>
     </tr> 
      
     <tr>
         <td>Numéro de lot&nbsp;:</td>
         <th>
              
             
               
                 
                 4070799
                 
                                                                  
                                          
               
                                                
         </th>
     </tr>  
     
     <tr>
         <td>Numéro de matricule&nbsp;:</td>
         <th>0034-33-9422-7-000-0000</th>
     </tr>  
     <tr>
         <td>Utilisation prédominante&nbsp;:</td>
         <th>Maison pour personnes retraitées autonomes</th>
     </tr>  
     <tr>
         <td>Numéro d'unité de voisinage&nbsp;:</td>
         <th>4882</th>
     </tr>  
     <tr>
         <td>Numéro de compte foncier&nbsp;:</td>
         <th>28 - F01810500</th>
     </tr> 
    </tbody></table>
</div>
            






 


   
   
   
   
   
   
  
<div class="table-responsive" id="section-2">
    <h2>2.&nbsp;Propriétaire</h2>
    <table class="table table-borderless table-condensed">
        
            <tbody><tr>
                <td width="50%">Nom&nbsp;:</td>
                <th width="50%">9427686 CANADA INC.</th>
            </tr>  
            <tr>
                <td>Statut aux fins d'imposition scolaire&nbsp;:</td>
                <th>Personne morale</th>
            </tr>
                
              
                <tr>
                    <td>Adresse postale&nbsp;:</td>
                    <th>2400    BOUL DANIEL-JOHNSON  , LAVAL QUEBEC, H7T 3A4</th>
                </tr>
            
            
            
                <tr>
                    <td>Date d'inscription au rôle&nbsp;:</td>
                    <th>
                    2015-10-02</th>
                </tr>
            
            
            
        
    </tbody></table>    
</div>  
            






<div class="table-responsive" id="section-3">
    <h2>3.&nbsp;Caractéristiques de l'unité d'évaluation</h2>
    <table class="table table-borderless table-condensed">
        <tbody><tr>
            <th colspan="3" width="50%"><h3>Caractéristiques du terrain</h3></th>
            <th colspan="3" width="50%"><h3>Caractéristiques du bâtiment principal</h3></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mesure frontale&nbsp;:</td>
            <th class="text-right">
                                    
            </th>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Nombre d'étages&nbsp;:</td>
            <th class="text-right">10</th>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>        
        <tr>
            <td>Superficie&nbsp;:</td>
            <th class="text-right">
                
                    
                    
                    
                       14&nbsp;196,30&nbsp;m<sup>2</sup>
                    
                
            </th>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Année de construction&nbsp;:</td>
            <th class="text-right">
                      
                      
                        2009
                      
                      
                 
            </th>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <th class="text-right"></th>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Aire d'étages&nbsp;:</td>
            <th class="text-right">
                   
                   
                   
                      28&nbsp;585,20&nbsp;m<sup>2</sup>
                                  
               
             </th>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3" width="50%">
                
                
            </th>
            <td>Genre de construction&nbsp;:</td>
            <th class="text-right"></th>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
              
          </td>
          <th class="text-right">
                
                 
                       
          </th>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Lien physique&nbsp;:</td>
            <th class="text-right"></th>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
              
          </td>
          <th class="text-right">
              
                                                              
              
          </th>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Nombre de logements&nbsp;: </td>
            <th class="text-right">247</th>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
              &nbsp;
          </td>
            <th class="text-right">
               </th>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Nombre de locaux non résidentiels&nbsp;:</td>
            <th class="text-right">6</th>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Nombre de chambres locatives&nbsp;:</td>
            <th class="text-right">56</th>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</div>  
            






<div class="table-responsive" id="section-4">
    <h2>4.&nbsp;Valeurs au rôle d'évaluation</h2>
    
    <table class="table table-borderless table-condensed">
        <tbody><tr>
            <th colspan="3" width="50%"><h3>Rôle courant</h3></th>
            <th colspan="3" width="50%"><h3>Rôle antérieur</h3></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="35%">Date de référence au marché&nbsp;:</td>
            <th width="15%" class="text-right">2021-07-01</th>
            <td></td>
            <td width="35%">Date de référence au marché&nbsp;:</td>
            <th width="15%" class="text-right">2018-07-01</th>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td>Valeur du terrain&nbsp;:</td>
            <th class="text-right">
                    
                    13&nbsp;429&nbsp;700&nbsp;$
                
            </th>
            <td></td>
            <td>Valeur de l'immeuble au rôle antérieur&nbsp;:</td>
            <th class="text-right">
                    
                    32&nbsp;070&nbsp;000&nbsp;$
                
            </th>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Valeur du bâtiment&nbsp;:</td>
            <th class="text-right">
                    
                    18&nbsp;990&nbsp;300&nbsp;$
                
            </th>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Valeur de l'immeuble&nbsp;:</td>
            <th class="text-right">
                    
                    32&nbsp;420&nbsp;000&nbsp;$
                
            </th>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</div>
            





<div class="table-responsive" id="section-5A">
    <h2>5.&nbsp;Répartition fiscale</h2>
    <!-- div class="table-responsive"-->
        <table id="repartitionTable2" class="table table-borderless table-condensed">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td colspan="2" width="40%">Catégorie et classe d'immeuble à des fins d'application<br>des taux de taxation&nbsp;:</td>
            <th class="text-lefht" colspan="2" width="60%">Non résidentielle classe 1A, Six logements et plus</th>
        </tr>
        
        </tbody></table>
        <br>
        <table id="repartitionTable2" class="table table-borderless table-condensed">
           <tbody>
               <tr>
                    <td width="20%">Valeur imposable de l'immeuble&nbsp;:</td>
                    <th width="20%" class="text-right">
                        
                          
                          32&nbsp;420&nbsp;000&nbsp;$             
                        
                    </th>
            <td width="30%">Valeur non imposable de l'immeuble&nbsp;:</td>
            <th width="30%" class="text-right">
              
                      
                        0&nbsp;$             
                               
                    </th>
             </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
    <!-- /div-->
</div>  
<div class="table-responsive" id="section-5">

</div>
```

Comment: On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] Thanks

Comment: Please either confirm the url of the page in question (if publicly available), or pos the page' html -- as text. Please also read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus Please see html code (in text format) as part of the recent post edit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the structure is not seriously different from the example, you could use the following approach, which first selects all `<th>` and then combines them with the corresponding `<td>` in a `dict comprehension`:

```
{
    (e.find_previous('td').get_text(strip=True).strip(':'),e.get_text(strip=True)) 
    for e in soup.select('th')
}
```

Use the `dict` to create your dataframe, [`set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to your key column and [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html). If you have multiple dataframes, simply [`.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) them to one:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div class="table-responsive" id="section-1"><h2>1.&nbsp;Identification de l'unité d'évaluation</h2><table class="table table-borderless table-condensed"><tbody><tr><td width="50%">Adresse&nbsp;:</td><th width="50%">325 Chemin de la Pointe-Sud</th></tr> <tr> <td>Arrondissement&nbsp;:</td> <th>Arrondissement de Verdun</th> </tr><tr> <td>Numéro de lot&nbsp;:</td> <th>4070799 </th> </tr><tr> <td>Numéro de matricule&nbsp;:</td> <th>0034-33-9422-7-000-0000</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Utilisation prédominante&nbsp;:</td> <th>Maison pour personnes retraitées autonomes</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Numéro d'unité de voisinage&nbsp;:</td> <th>4882</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Numéro de compte foncier&nbsp;:</td> <th>28 - F01810500</th> </tr> </tbody></table></div> <div class="table-responsive" id="section-2"><h2>2.&nbsp;Propriétaire</h2><table class="table table-borderless table-condensed"><tbody><tr><td width="50%">Nom&nbsp;:</td><th width="50%">9427686 CANADA INC.</th></tr><tr><td>Statut aux fins d'imposition scolaire&nbsp;:</td><th>Personne morale</th></tr><tr><td>Adresse postale&nbsp;:</td><th>2400BOUL DANIEL-JOHNSON, LAVAL QUEBEC, H7T 3A4</th></tr><tr><td>Date d'inscription au rôle&nbsp;:</td><th>2015-10-02</th></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="table-responsive" id="section-3"><h2>3.&nbsp;Caractéristiques de l'unité d'évaluation</h2><table class="table table-borderless table-condensed"><tbody><tr><th colspan="3" width="50%"><h3>Caractéristiques du terrain</h3></th><th colspan="3" width="50%"><h3>Caractéristiques du bâtiment principal</h3></th></tr><tr><td>Mesure frontale&nbsp;:</td><th class="text-right"></th><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Nombre d'étages&nbsp;:</td><th class="text-right">10</th><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>Superficie&nbsp;:</td><th class="text-right"> 14&nbsp;196,30&nbsp;m<sup>2</sup></th><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Année de construction&nbsp;:</td><th class="text-right">2009 </th><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th class="text-right"></th><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Aire d'étages&nbsp;:</td><th class="text-right"> 28&nbsp;585,20&nbsp;m<sup>2</sup></th> <td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><th colspan="3" width="50%"></th><td>Genre de construction&nbsp;:</td><th class="text-right"></th><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th class="text-right"></th><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Lien physique&nbsp;:</td><th class="text-right"></th><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th class="text-right"></th><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Nombre de logements&nbsp;: </td><th class="text-right">247</th><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><th class="text-right"> </th><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Nombre de locaux non résidentiels&nbsp;:</td><th class="text-right">6</th><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><th>&nbsp;</th><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Nombre de chambres locatives&nbsp;:</td><th class="text-right">56</th><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table></div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

pd.DataFrame(
    {
        (e.find_previous('td').get_text(strip=True).strip(':'),e.get_text(strip=True)) 
        for e in soup.select('th')
    }
).set_index(0).T.to_csv('myfile.csv', index=False)
```

##### Output

|  | Date d'inscription au rôle | Arrondissement | Statut aux fins d'imposition scolaire | Date d'inscription au rôle | Nombre de logements | Numéro d'unité de voisinage | Numéro de compte foncier | Utilisation prédominante | Nombre de chambres locatives | Numéro de matricule | Adresse postale | Aire d'étages | Nombre d'étages | Date d'inscription au rôle | Mesure frontale | Lien physique | Adresse | Superficie | Nombre de locaux non résidentiels |  | Numéro de lot | Année de construction | Genre de construction | Nom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Caractéristiques du bâtiment principal | Arrondissement de Verdun | Personne morale | 2015-10-02 | 247 | 4882 | 28 - F01810500 | Maison pour personnes retraitées autonomes | 56 | 0034-33-9422-7-000-0000 | 2400BOUL DANIEL-JOHNSON, LAVAL QUEBEC, H7T 3A4 | 28 585,20 m2 | 10 | Caractéristiques du terrain |  |  | 325 Chemin de la Pointe-Sud | 14 196,30 m2 | 6 |  | 4070799 | 2009 |  | 9427686 CANADA INC. |